# TexStudio Error: Could not start the command: biber "..."

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, biber, ubuntu, linux

I have a problem in TeXstudio that I cannot run biber. I get the following error message.

> Error: Could not start the command: biber ...

Biber is installed on my PC with POP!_OS 21.04 / Ubuntu Linux. But when I run biber in the terminal it works fine, just not directly in TeXstudio. I already tried to change the path in the settings to "/usr/bin/biber", but unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: Exactly what latex did you install? And what does `which biber` say in a terminal?

Comment: Which biber says "/usr/bin/biber". How can I find out which LaTeX I have installed?

Comment: I have a suspicion that you might have two latex installations. Note that on a properly configured system you should not need to specify `/usr/bin/biber` in the configuration. I'd like you to do two things: (1) What does `which pdflatex` say? (2) In your texstudio save the following example and post its log file from your system from compiling it in texstudio as you normally do your latex: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}hello\end{document}`. The generated `.log` will tell us where `texstudio` is running things from.

Comment: Which pdflatex says "/usr/bin/biber". The .log file says: https://pastebin.com/EYrgxL97

Comment: Say what? `which pdflatex` in a terminal returns `/usr/bin/biber`? Then there's something wrong with your system. Btw add the contents of the log to you ur question, it will not fit in a comment

Comment: Its not a real solution.. but i had the same problem with TeXmaker(flatpack). I removed it and installed the debian version. Then it worked fine. OS: Pop!_OS 21.10